# Available slots in a smartCard provider working with Java 9+

Tags: java, smartcard, java-9

In Java 8 we can do something like this:

```
PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance("/usr/local/lib/libsiecap11.so", "C_GetFunctionList", null, false); 
long[] slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);
```

But in Java 9 PKCS11 was deprecated and now I can't find any alternative.

Comment: Any updates if the issue got fixed ??

Comment: @Vishwa Ratna I didn't find a solution...

Comment: did you reported the problem on Github??

Comment: @Vishwa Ratna No, You can do it, if you want...

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/open-eid/cdoc4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/openeid/cdoc4j/token/pkcs11 , i think someone has added a wayaround for java9+ , check it and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

From Java-9 [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-4C366313-33B9-458C-A845-33D0C8A9C367):

> Java applications can use the existing JCA and JCE APIs to access
>   `PKCS#11` tokens through the `SunPKCS11` provider.

For reference: I compared [Java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) doc and [Java-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-4C366313-33B9-458C-A845-33D0C8A9C367) doc and there seems not much difference when it comes to `PKCS#11`

**Edit:**

I ran Op's code on JDK 1.8 and i was able to execute it while when i change to JDK 11 , I got the below error as some `Libs` were missing.

**Missing Libs:**

```
 sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11;
 sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception;
```

I request you to open a incident on **github**, to get this fixed.

Comment: Could you write a example for obtain the slots in Java-9, like I did in Java-8?

Comment: @Betwen , you seems to be right, the libs are missing from jdk 9+.